# Using Subclipse - merge

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I created a project, I added it to the repository to the trunk. I made a few changes. I'm looking for the correct way to add a new branch now. He wanted me to work a bit over the appearance of the application. Then, if everything comes out, I wanted to combine the projects into a single new version.

How to do it, ask for directions, links.

Thank you and best regards.

PS: Exactly, I mean that if you do everything as I think it is ok it shows me no call from 5 to 6 on the diagram:

[image](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/4716/beznazwy2wp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Subclipse subpage for graphs (http://subclipse.tigris.org/graph.html) it states:

> When the cache is built, it does not gather any merge information, and when you bring up a graph you will not see any merge information. However, for any given revision in the graph, you can select it and take the "Refresh revision" option. That will go out and get the merge information for that revision, store it in the cache, and re-draw the graph. Using the toolbar, you can refresh all of the revisions on the graph at once, although performance for that option is not always great either.

So you should manually refresh revision graph in order to see 'red merge arrows'. Click on "Reload arrows" and choose "Graph revisions".

[image: Revision graph toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

Instructions on [merging and branching in Subclipse](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/03/how-to-setup-subclipse-project-to/).

Answer (score -2):

First, you would do an `svn cp` of revision one on the trunk to the branch directory.  Then, `svn switch` to the branch and work on the changes.  Once they are approved, you would commit everything to the branch, `svn switch` back to the trunk, and then perform an `svn merge` of the branch back onto the trunk.  Once SVN has completed the merge, you would test the codebase on the trunk to insure it is functioning correctly and all the capability has been properly merged and do an `svn commit` to complete the merging of the branch to the trunk.

Comment: I wished I would get something like this: http://subclipse.tigris.org/images/graph/options.png

Comment: The revision graph is a way of exploring the history after you have done these changes.  You cannot create the branches or make changes from the graph.  All of the above commands are available on the Team menu in Eclipse

Comment: The question was regarding Subclipse, not the cli.

Comment: So gonna be the video and explain what I mean, so it will be best.